# Is there a simple GUI to create SQL Server Queries and operations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint, user-interface

I have created a Database in SQL Server using MS SQL Management studio.
I'm looking for a simple GUI tool to easily search in the database or add new data to the database.
for example, if my database stores links for pictures - each picture has some tables like location, objects, animals, lighting etc.
I want to be able to search the database, so i can choose of a box list for each table instead of Querying through the SQL.

i understand this can be done with Sharepoint and MS Access, but i recon it's too complicated.
any thoughts and ideas? 
thnx.

Comment: Why don't you google it?  This site is for programming questions, not to recommend tools.

Comment: Hi Rick, I googled it, couldn't find a solution that fits my needs. I was hoping people experienced with SQL Databases has encountered this situation before and could probably help me with ease.

Comment: Only tool I know of close to what you are asking for would be the query designer in SSMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [EMS SQL Manager for SQL Server](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/studio/mssql) - it has free `Lite` version which ones limitations are acceptable.

Also you may try [DevArt's dbForge Studio for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/ru/dbforge/sql/studio/) - this product's progress is very impressive. It's one of the best solutions for managing SQL Server.